# How to make gif animation visible for a specific time in JavaFX?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, animated-gif

I'm making a simple game in JavaFX and I want to display animations when characters fighting. When I click 'attack' button I want to display 'fight.gif' animation. When not clicking anything I want another 'waitForAction.gif' to be displayed. Problem is I want this 'fight.gif' to be displayed for a specific time, so the whole animation can be seen before 'waitForAction.gif' will be displayed again.

So my question is:

Are GIF's a good idea? If Yes, how to control them?
If not, how to make these animations work?

If you have problem with understanding I can post pictures of what I want to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Timeline`. E.g. to display the gif for 2 seconds, you could do:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> { /* display fight.gif */}),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> { /* hide fight.gif */})
);
timeline.play();
```

The way this works is that the timeline consists of a series of key frames. Each key frame has a time associated with it (the time point on the timeline) and, in this example, an action to be invoked at that time. So in this case, zero seconds after the timeline is started, `fight.gif` is displayed, and 2 seconds after the timeline is started, `fight.gif` is hidden. The timeline is started by invoking its `play()` method.

In general, any time you want your UI to do something at, or for, some specific time, an animation of some kind may well provide an easy solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now animation works, but now I have more complicated problem. There are two fight animations (one for playerAttack, and for computerAttack). It's because I don't want to display hit animation when one of them misses.

The problem is with synchronization - when player hits and computer hits, two animations should be displayed, but program ignores first animation I don't know what to do with this.

By the way I do this with ImageView and .setImage method - is that bad idea?

I'm completely green, so sorry for misunderstandings, but I try hard to make this work :)

Comment: @AsiaRafi Please try to structure your questions so they make coherent question-answer pairs when answered. It seems this answers the question you originally posted. The question you posted in your comment (which I don't really understand, tbh) should either be a new question, or should be part of the original question. A question and answer should not become an ongoing conversation to create your specific project: that is of little or no use to other users of the site.

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstandings, I'll post another question. I just have a new problem after solving the first one.

Comment: @AsiaRafi Before you post another question, you need to do some research and try to solve it yourself. It has been at most 40 minutes since you actually encountered this problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users (which is a bit extreme, but should give you the idea).

Comment: When you added explainantion it's more clear now. I solved problem with synchronization using .seconds properly. And for people who wants to animate using this I truly recommend making an array with single images and display them as keyframes, because GIFs causes a lot of bugs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Timeline to give interval duration

```
                            Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

                            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(3), (ActionEvent event1) -> {

                                try {
                                 //put your code here
                                } catch (Exception exception) {

                                }

                            }));
                            timeline.play();
```